# I need to dynamically add more fields to a form and have the new fields inputs values change as well

Tags: javascript

[**I have a jsfiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vegas/2gPfn/) of the script I'm using to dynamically add rows to a field but have a problem.

On my form I have the 1st row that I want to duplicate with the script. The row consists of 6 inputs named `job_date1`, `tech_name1`, `cost_code1`, `pay_rate1`, `total_hours1`, and `sub_total1`.

When the second row is created via the script I now need the new rows input names to be set by the script if possible to `job_date2`, `tech_name2`, `cost_code2` and so on and with each new row created I need the end digit to move up one.

Here is the code:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); 
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) { 
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null !== chkbox && true === chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            } 
        }
        } 
        catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
}
```

Comment: Change `onLoad` to `no wrap in <head>`...

Comment: @Zenith Thanks now the fiddle works

Comment: @Zenith the actual problem is in the question, I need to change the field input values with each new row that is created.

Comment: @Zenith Thanks I saw that edit I was just doing the same thing to clear up the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
newcell.children[0].name = newcell.children[0].name + rowCount;
```

As you count each newly added row, add that variable to each of the input elements.

[**Here's the jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2gPfn/9/) (be sure to check your console when you run the function to see the console log).

For the first log, it returns:

```
chk1
txt1 
tech_name1 
cost_code1
txt1
```

For the second element that's created

```
chk2
txt2 
tech_name2 
cost_code2
txt2
```

etc.

Comment: That works great, but let me ask you this, is it possible to remove the add and delete buttons and just use the check box to add and remove rows? so if I have the default row in place and put a check in the box will add another row with a check box and putting a check in that box will add another and so on and removing the check box from the previous row removes the row after it?

Comment: or maybe a radio button? kind of like a toggle!

Comment: Nevermind as you can see by the jsFiddle I've found the solution to using just the checkbox

Comment: I actually have a problem with the script, I need to be able to pass the input 'id' as well as the 'name' into the new rows. I have a script that totals up the inputs based on their 'id' names.

Answer (score 2):

I have a simpler suggestion. Instead of having `job_date1`, `job_date2`, etc., name your fields `job_date[]` (all of the job date fields).

E.g. PHP automatically recognizes this and `$_POST["job_date"]` would be an array with all the values for job date in the order they appear on the html page. 
So instead of `$_POST["job_date" . $i]` you would use `$_POST["job_date"][$i]`.

I don't know what technology you use for the backend, but I'm sure you can achieve the same effect.

It will be more robust and elegant and you don't have to care about re-numbering when you add nor remove rows.

---

*Edit:* More details about this technique in PHP can be found in [PHP FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) and Example #3 [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

Comment: so would I change my variables from lets say $item_qty1=$_POST['item_qty1']; $item_qty2=$_POST['item_qty2']; $item_qty3=$_POST['item_qty3'];  to this $item_qty=$_POST['item_qty'][$I];   I don't need to specify qty1, qty2 and so on?

Comment: The equivalent of `$item_qty1=$_POST['item_qty1']; $item_qty2=$_POST['item_qty2'];` would be `$item_qty1=$_POST['item_qty'][1]; $item_qty2=$_POST['item_qty'][2];`. You can treat `$_POST['item_qty']` as an array. I've added links to the documentation where you can see the usage.